# On click callback from Google Maps Flutter plugin

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I'm creating an app that will allow the user to pick a location on a map and save it. I'm using Google's google_maps_flutter package for that. 
 
I was able to create an intractable map view (scroll, zoom) and I want to get a callback whenever the user presses on the map to get the location pressed. 
Anyone knows how to do it?

If there isn't anything like that, would I be able to create the same thing using a  Google Maps URL and the WebView widget?

Comment: I believe that at this point you can't get the tapped position because there isn't callback listeners for that purpose. However, you can handle tap events on markers or even its labels, but you'll need to provide the coordinates yourself to create it.

Comment: Alright thanks. I'm currently looking at alternatives in the 'no longer in development' package cirrus_map_view. Maybe I'll have luck there.

Comment: Give the official maps some time, it’s still on preview release, 3 months ago it wasn’t even available to iOS, now it is. I believe that it will support in a near future and you are always free to add the feature yourself and make a PR for it, after all, never forget that flutter is made with love of its community :)

Comment: I wish I was skilled enough in the field to write it myself. Right now I'm trying the other plugin while keeping the code for the official one. When the time comes and itll have all the features I need, I'll switch back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two pull requests ([#985](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/985), [#1121](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1121)) that give you onclick callback. Both currently open but are supposed to be merged soon. 
 
As an alternative, a [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1049) is currently in review for updating the marker's location on drag-drop.

Comment: I ran the version 0.2.0 but I do not see the onTap method. I only see the onMarkerTapped method. Could you please provide an example of how to use it

Comment: Updated my answer to give the correct pull requests.

Comment: I can't find any way to do this in version google_maps_flutter: 0.4.0